# How to compact if operator for this statement in Unity C#

Tags: c#, debugging, if-statement, unity-game-engine, ternary-operator

In "Unity" we often debug to console.

```
public bool printInConsole;

void Start()
{
    if ( printInConsole ) Debug.Log("Starting and printing...");
}
```

I would like to call this Unity function using the compact ? ternary operator.
How do I write a statement for this in Unity using C#?

Comment: What is your "false" case?

Comment: Do you have an else?

Comment: do not show in console. No I do not has a else

Comment: If you don't have an else case, then you don't need a ternary operator.  Maybe you should explain a little more about what you're trying to achieve....

Comment: Not only have no no else, but `Debug.Log` is probably `void`, right? So there's nothing for the expression to return either.

Comment: I change the title from ternary operator. to compact if operator

Comment: But there's no such thing as a "compact if operator", so again..what are you looking to achieve that you haven't already with your existing code?

Comment: The conditional operator needs expressions (that result in a value), not plain statemants (like your Debug.Log)

Comment: Something like this: printInConsole ? Debug.Log("Starting and printing...");

Comment: @SoaringLines, no you can't do that. there is no such thing present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to make an ***if*** statement more compact than:

```
if ( printInConsole ) Debug.Log("Starting and printing...");
```

A better visual way, as "*Rahul*" points out, that is more readable is:

```
if ( printInConsole ) 
   Debug.Log( "Starting and printing..." );
```

As "*Genos*" mention, is not correct to use a C# compact ternary operator as for example:

```
printInConsole ? Debug.Log("Starting and printing...");
```

Because it needs a second else expression.

It is possible to do it inside the function, but the result is not more compact, simple or readable.:

```
Debug.Log(printInConsole ? "Running and printing..." : "\n");
```

"*itsme86*" and my conventional solution is to create a specific compact function method. In this way, the calling function is more compact.

```
Mss("Starting and printing..." );
```

In my case the full Unity code example will be:

```
public bool printInConsole;

void Start()
{
    Mss("Starting and printing..." );
}

private void Mss(string consoleMessage)
{
    if (printInConsole)
        Debug.Log(consoleMessage + "\n");
}
```

Another solution is to assign to a keyboard button a custom macro to prints out:

```
if ( printInConsole ) 
   Debug.Log( "" + "\n");
```

*Please since I'm not English, I pray you to improve my answer.*

Answer (score 1):

In your case since you only want to print when condition meets you are good with `if` block and there is no need of using ternary operator.

```
if ( printInConsole ) 
   Debug.Log("Starting and printing...");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have several things you want to log and you just want to avoid the "if / log" cycle, you could create a method:

```
private void LogIt(string msg)
{
    if (printInConsole)
        Debug.Log(msg);
}
```

Then you'd just call `LogIt()` every time you wanted to log something.

Comment: That's certainly dry-er.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR Use the if:

```
if ( printInConsole ) Debug.Log("Starting and printing...");
```

The syntax of a ternary expression in C# is as follows:

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

In your scenario the ternary operator cannot be used since:

1. It requires two expressions: one in case the `condition` is `true`(first_expression) and another one for `false`(second_expression).
2. Ternary operator expressions must return a value, and `Debug.Log()` returns `void`.

You could invent some crazy way for fitting your logic in a ternary operator, like wrapping the `Debug.log()` call in an `Action` delegate, but that would be waste, since the whole point of a ternary operator is to make your code simpler...

Answer (score -4):

```
if(printInConsole)?Debug.Log("Starting and printing..."): _you_else_condition_
```

Comment: You're mixing VB.NET ternary operator syntax with C#.  AND, the OP stated clearly, like 7 minutes ago, that he doesn't have an "else" condition.  AND `Debug.Log` doesn't return anything, so this won't compile.

Comment: No this answer give a error message: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `?'